# Why is this building still requiring an entrance?

Tags: prison-architect

[image: I clearly have an entrance...]

Just as the title says, I have a building with an entrance, that still requires and entrance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that PA does not recognise entrances placed on the corners of foundations. You need to put the entrance at least one square away from any corner. In your case, although you have built a new building up against an existing wall, PA considers this a separate building and the square you have put the entrance on is a "corner" (even though it won't be once the foundation has been built.

When you want to put an entrance up against another wall this can mean placing an entrance where you don't want it just to get the foundation built; then having to dismantle/brick up the original entrance and add a new entrance where you *actually* want it.

Answer (score -1):

Usually when this happens, I just take the foundation tool and go over the area in the same dimensions again, this usually fixes it for me.